# Problems with log4j2

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have two problems with log4j2:

1. I cannot figure out how to specify the log root level in the command line.

I execute runnable jar with *log4j2.xml* config file

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml  -jar my.jar
```

The *log4j2.xml* has default loggers root log level set to INFO. But sometimes I need to specify DEBUG.

2. *-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml* does not work on Windows though it works fine on Mac and Linux. *log4j2.xml* does exist in current folder.

I get error when executing above mentioned command line with Windows PowerShell

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .configurationFile=log4j2.xml
```

I tried *-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file://log4j2.xml* or *-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./log4j2.xml* or *-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file://<full_path_to_log4j2.xml>* the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a property named "rootLevel" as

   ${sys:rootLevel:=INFO}

then on your root Logger specify

```
<Root level="${rootLevel}">
```

The root level will now default to Info and you can override it with -DrootLevel=DEBUG on the command line.

2. The problem is the dot in the property name. On Windows you need to put it in quotes.

Comment: 1. I soled this problem by providing command line argument that specifies the log level and then using it with org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.setRootLevel(level) to set the log level dynamically at run time.

2. I cannot make Windows PowerShell work. I tried put the log file in quotes or double-quotes and get the same error.

Interestingly, the plain Windows shell CMD works just fine, the problem seems to happen only with windows PowerShell.